# Swashbuckle or NSwag documentation for dynamic request body

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, swashbuckle, nswag

I need to document all different request models for the endpoint:

```
public Task<SomeResponse> Post(JObject request) 
{
    ...
}
```

What options do I have besides just writing detailed comments about expected request models or creating endpoints per model?

Comment: Please, show some exmaples of what you need to do. For example, can the JObject be absolutely anything or there are several cocnrete cases, or does it have a minimum common structure for all the cases?

Comment: IMO, you would benefit from splitting this `Post` method into multiple endpoints, each accepting a different strongly-typed model.  That said, I don't know if you can document the different possible expected models as-is.

Comment: @JotaBe JObject can be absolutely anything.

Comment: @Amy too many to split...

Comment: If it can be absolutely anything, I don't see how it can be documented other than "The payload can be absolutely anything."

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can. Since the payload is dynamic, how can NSwag know?

Comment: By providing `[SwaggerRequest(typeof(MyRequestModel))]` attribute or some similar option.

Comment: The correct (tool independent) attribute is `ProducesResponseTypeAttribute` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.producesresponsetypeattribute?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Comment: No, it’s not. This is for the response type, what he wants is for the payload (the parameter).